# Haskell make recursion for Chars in String

Tags: haskell, recursion

I want to create game Magic 15 Puzzle in Haskell I have function `set :: [[Char]] -> Char -> [[Char]]` .
It switches Char with empty space in [[Char]].

```
*Main> pp puzzle2
AC DE
FBHIJ
KGLNO
PQMRS
UVWXT
*Main> pp (set puzzle2 'C')
A CDE
FBHIJ
KGLNO
PQMRS
UVWXT
*Main>
```

Now I want to do recursion for `[Char]` (or `String`) like this (To do `set` xs for previous `set` x)

```
puzzle :: Result -> [Char] -> Result
puzzle gameboard (x:xs) =  set (set (x:xs) x) xs
```

But compilation says it is error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
```

I expect this output:

```
*Main> pp(puzzle puzzle2 "CB")                    
ABCDE
F HIJ
KGLNO
PQMRS
UVWXT
```

What can I do to solve this? Thanks a lot in advance for answer!

Whole Code:

```
import Data.Char
type Result = [String]
pp :: Result -> IO ()
pp x = putStr (concat (map (++"\n") x))

puzzle2 :: [[Char]]
puzzle2 = ["AC DE",
           "FBHIJ",
           "KGLNO",
           "PQMRS",
           "UVWXT"]





getCords board x = head ( head [[(row_index, column_index) |(column_index, char) <- zip[1..] row, x == char] |(row_index,row)<- zip [1..]board,x `elem` row])
getRow board c = fst ( getCords board c)
getCol board c = snd ( getCords board c)
check ch1 ch2 board =  (getRow board ch2 == getRow board ch1 + 1 || getRow board ch2 == getRow board ch1 - 1) && (getCol board ch1 == getCol board ch2) || ((getRow board ch1 == getRow board ch2) && (getCol board ch2 == getCol board ch1 + 1 || getCol board ch2 == getCol board ch1 - 1) )





set gameboard x | check x ' ' gameboard = [[if ch == ' ' then x else if ch == x then ' ' else ch | ch<- line] | line<-gameboard]
                | not (check x ' ' gameboard ) = [[ch | ch<- line] | line<-gameboard]





puzzle :: Result -> [Char] -> Result
puzzle gameboard (x:xs) =  set (set (x:xs) x) xs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the last function to

```
puzzle :: Result -> [Char] -> Result
puzzle g [] = g
puzzle g (x:xs) =  puzzle (set g x) xs
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, what does `puzzle g [] = g` means?

Comment: it means that for empty string it doesn't changes, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is the condition of end of recursion.